# Get the list index range of a list depending on the values

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
Values = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5]
```

I would like to get the index ranges depending on the values. For example, for the value "0" I would like to get:

```
IndexRange0 = range(0,2) = [0,1]    
#the element "0" is taking the positions 0 and 1 of the list "Values"
```

for the value "1" I'd like to get:

```
IndexRange1 = range(2,7) = [2,3,4,5,6]
```

etc.
In the end, I would like to get a "list of these ranges", let's say:

```
FinalOutput = [IndexRange0, IndexRange1, .... IndexRange5]
```

I have no clue how to make this without using expensive constructions with loops and bad work-arounds. Any idea?

**Note**: the numbers will always be progressively increasing. The length of the ranges is variables (this time there are 2 "zeros", next time they might be 5 etc.) but its order is always increasing one by one (there would be a set of 0, then a set of 1, then a set of 2 etc. until a non-fix integer *n*). Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't figure out what you call "expensive constructions". This is a O(N) problem with a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either `bisect` or `itertools.takewhile`, depending on how you plan to use it.

With bisect:

```
import bisect

def index_range(n, lst):
    return (bisect.bisect_left(lst, n), bisect.bisect_right(lst, n))

def final_output(rng, lst):
    return [index_range(n, lst) for n in rng]

values = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5]
print(final_output(range(0,6), values))
```

gives

```
[(0, 2), (2, 7), (7, 10), (10, 16), (16, 19), (19, 23)]
```

Comment: Just tried this one. The numbers are not necessarily between 0 and 5 of course, but I can just do `UniqueValues = list(set(Values))` and then iterate for each value of the `UniqueValues` your function. Amazing, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
Values = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5]
output = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(Values), key=itemgetter(1)):
    start = next(g)[0]
    for end, _ in g: pass
    output.append((start, end+1))
print output
```

Output:

```
[(0, 2), (2, 7), (7, 10), (10, 16), (16, 19), (19, 23)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the values are always increasing by one, here is another way to do it without explicitly counting the number of occurrences for each value:

```
>>> Values = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5]
>>> starts = [Values.index(i) for i in range(Values[-1] + 1)] + [len(Values)]
>>> print starts
[0, 2, 7, 10, 16, 19, 23]
>>> ranges = [range(starts[i], starts[i + 1]) for i in range(len(starts) - 1)]
>>> for r in ranges:
...    print r
... 
[0, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21, 22]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know each number's range you have to save it in a list to keep a reference to that number. assume your list had gaps between numbers like this one

```
L=[0,0,0,2,2,2,4,5,6,6,7]
```

still an increasing sequence but you can't know what value is the second range for unless you keep reference to that value,
here is a simple code for that:

```
prev=L[0]
f_index=0
l_index=-1
info = {}
for index, item in enumerate(L):
    if prev != item:
        l_index=index-1
        info[prev]=(f_index,l_index)
        prev=item
        f_index=index
info[prev]=(f_index,index)
print info
```

the result will be as following:

```
{0: (0, 2), 2: (3, 5), 4: (6, 6), 5: (7, 7), 6: (8, 9), 7: (10, 10)}
```

now you can deal with it as a 2D list to make the range you need i.e.

```
range(info[number][0],info[number][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read the first value
start a run
until end-of-list
  read a value
  if differs from current
    finish the run
    start a new run
  else
    lengthen the run
finish the run
```

Comment: Yes, I've built something like this (maybe even a bit longer), but Hugh's solution above looks much more elegant I'd say, 3 lines of code and perfect result ;)

Comment: This solution takes time `O(m.lg(n))`, for `m` distinct values among `n`. Knowing nothing about `m`, the actual complexity could range from `O(lg(n))` to `O(n.log(n))`. But there is a little cheating in the sense that you asked to report all indices, not just the splitting indices. So this solution is at best `O(n)` and at worst `O(n.lg(n))`.